# open a web view hyperlink in default app in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink

I have this link in web view for

1. Instagram : https://www.instagram.com/p/BTqnxrbBDQY/
2. Twitter : https://twitter.com/TechCrunch/status/879757787839868929
3. GooglePlus: https://plus.google.com/+Htimobile/posts/RBCa3KYoaoM

When clicked on any link, I have to open them in their default app and if the app is not installed, it should open in browser

I achieved this in Android using Send Intent but Unable to get a clue in IOS Swift

I am able to open in Safari but not in default app.

I have the following keys in info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>instagram</string>
<string>fb</string>
</array>
```

The following code opens Instagram app but not the url

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked {
        let url = URL(string: "instagram://app")
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
        } else {
            // if Instagram app is not installed, open URL inside Safari
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(request.url!)
        }



        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

any help will be appreciated